# WinForms dynamic data | Data not showing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which generates an email and then generates a report using values from a database all done is a separate class from the code behind of the form. I created some sort of window where the progress is recorded simply by the following:

- I created an empty string in my class with the email and reporting
  logic
- Inside the code where the report is generated e.g. I have put "Making
  report... 25%";
- I repeated this for a couple other places
- I then set the label.Text property to the field to the string

The text does not appear nor change as I had anticipated since.
Lets say **Form1** is the form before the progress form and **Form2** is the progress form.

In form 1 when the "GO" button is clicked the event handler creates a new instance of **Form2** followed be **form2.Show();**.
Inside Form2 I have done:

```
public partial class EmailLauncherProgress : Form
{
    ExportRecords exportRecords = new ExportRecords();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label1.Text = exportRecords.reportProgress;
    }
}



public class ExportRecords
{
        public string reportProgress = "";
        public string exportFileName = "";

        public PrepareEmailAndReport()
        {
          MakeReport();
          MakeEmail();
          //other logic
        }

        public MakeReport()
        {
        //some logic
        reportprogress += "25%"
        }

        public MakeEmail()
        {
        //some logic
        reportprogress += "75%"
        }
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{

        ExportRecords exportRecords = new ExportRecords();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //other logic to load form
        }

        private void toolStripButton1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 emll = new Form1();

            if (emll.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {   
                /*GetRecipients just gets recipients from a tickbox returns 
                  as a list.*/
                exportRecords.PrepareAndEmailReport(emll.GetRecipients());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what is `exportRecords` in this code? You haven't given us enough code to understand and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @ADyson . I hope this helps a little, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok thanks. Very simply, you are not giving a value to reportProgress. It goes like this: You create a new ExportRecords object. By default, reportProgress is empty (since that's how you define it in the class). Then you ask for its value. Its value is still empty, so that's what you see on the screen.

Comment: So what would I have to do to recall the property each time I append the string as shown in the MakeReport and MakeEmail method.

Comment: You haven't run those methods. If you run either of them before asking for the value of reportsProgress, you'll see the result.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a confusion between different instances of the ExportRecords class - did you make another copy of it inside Form1, by any chance? You need to share the same instance between the two forms for this to work the way you're imagining.

Comment: Currently I have a method called **PrepareEmailandReport()** inside the ExportRecords class and it is the method which calls **MakeReport()** and **MakeEmail()**. Form1 does not have an instance of **ExportRecords** within it.

Comment: Ok. And where do you call PrepareEmailandReport() within your code? You don't, from what I can see. It's not helping that you haven't shown us all the connecting parts.

Comment: and if somewhere you _do_ call that method within Form2, you would still need to update the label text again afterwards with `label1.Text = exportRecords.reportProgress;` in order to fetch the latest value from the class. So maybe you never call the method, or maybe you never update the label, or maybe both. Or maybe something else entirely. We can't be sure what the real problem is because we're lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies. Its not as easy for me either because I am picking up someone's poor code. The PrepareEmailandReport() method is called in another form (this form is the main form with all the options. I have edited the main post to reflect this.

Comment: "The PrepareEmailandReport() method is called in another form"...which means it must be called against _another instance of ExportRecords_ - i.e. almost the exact thing you denied was happening in an earlier comment. (>.<) That must be the case because the instance you created inside Form2 (and from which you're trying to read the value) never has that method called on it. Separate instances of a class have separate copies of their variables, as I'm sure you know. If you want to re-use the class between forms then you need to pass the instance variable between the forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use an event:

```
public class ExportRecords
{
    public delegate void ExportRecordsHandler(int percentage);
    public event ExportRecordsHandler ExportRecordsProgressChanged;

    public void Execute()
    {
         //Executes your whole Process
         MakeReport(); //Reports Progress up to  25%
         MakeEmail();  //Reports Progress up to  75%
         SendEmail();  //Reports Progress up to 100%
    }

    public void MakeReport()
    {
         //some logic
         ExportRecordsProgressChanged?.Invoke(25);
    }

    public void MakeEmail()
    {
        //some logic
        ExportRecordsProgressChanged?.Invoke(75);
    }
}
```

So in your App you can do this:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ExportRecords records = new ExportRecords();
    records.ExportRecordsProgressChanged += Progress_Changed;
    records.Execute(); //Run your actual process.
}

public void Progress_Changed(int percentage)
{
    //Event Handler get's called when ever the Event is invoked.
    label1.Text = $"{percentage}%";
}
```

Comment: Hi Felix! Thanks for your input. I implemented it quite nicely and after debugging I can see my label1.Text was assigned 25% however it did not change on the front end i.e. my label was still blank. Can you please help with this?

Comment: I used the refresh method and everything is good now! Thanks so much again!